# Does postgres single-user mode use postgresql.conf settings?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Does running postgres in single-user mode (`--single` argument) cause postgres to start and use the settings present in the `postgresql.conf` file in the data directory defined by the `-D` option?

I am doing some maintenance with postgres in single user mode. I want to ensure that while running in single user mode that it has the correct resource allocation available. I have already set these resources in `postgresql.conf` and the work as expected when running in normal (not single-user) mode. Is the same config file used when running in single-user mode as long as its present in the defined data directory?

My specific goal is to run a `VACUUM FREEZE` on a 1.6TB table to cope with a multixact wraparound issue. My `postgresql.conf` is loaded up with higher than normal (for us) maintenance_work_mem settings. If these settings are not read when running in single-user mode I need to know so I can apply them manually using the `-c` flag I think. I am specifically seeking an answer as to if the config is loaded, Q&A about my `FREEZE` or specific tuning should happen elsewhere.

I think I could verify this with `pg_settings` however I am now 3 hours in to a long running maintenance operation. I would prefer not to stop and restart that maintenance if another user or a manpage will confirm that my `postgresql.conf` settings are applied.

I am running PG 9.4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `postgresql.conf` and `postgresql.auto.conf` will be read and used in single-user mode as usual.

Parameters you specify with `-c` options will override the settings from the configuration files.

You are doing the right thing.